# For Loop NullPointerException with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

First of all, I apologize for my bad english, it's not my primary language. 
I'm having a problem with my code when it's reading an excel file (xlsx). The first time I used my code it works perfectly, but now I can't use it. 
The excel content is printed on the console, but next to it there is a NullPointerException that is caused by the for loop marked with the (-->>>). 
If anyone can help me, I would be very thankful, this code has given me several headaches.

```
package modleerjava;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class leerExcel {
public void readExcel(String rutaFile,String nombreFile, String sheetName ) 
 throws IOException {
    File file = new File ("C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/prueba.xlsx"); 
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);  
    XSSFWorkbook excelWorkbook ; 
    excelWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    Sheet excelSheet = excelWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName); 
    int filasCount = excelSheet.getLastRowNum()-excelSheet.getFirstRowNum(); 

    for (int i=0; i< filasCount+1 ; i++) { 
        Row filas;
        filas = excelSheet.getRow(i);

 -->>>  for (int j=0 ; j < filas.getLastCellNum(); j++) { 
            System.out.print(filas.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }       

}

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it (sorry can't format the link)

Comment: Please debug your code. It sounds like your `i` goes out of bounds for row numbers in the sheet, and it's caused by strange computation of `filasCount`. But the only way to make sure is to debug, and we don't have your data.

Comment: Must be data issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sheet probably has missing rows or cells. The best way to iterate over a spreadsheet in poi is using the `for each` syntax like this.

```
package modleerjava;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

public class leerExcel {
public void readExcel(String rutaFile,String nombreFile, String sheetName ) 
    throws IOException {
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/prueba.xlsx"));
    Sheet excelSheet = wb.getSheet(sheetName); 

    for (Row filas: excelSheet) { 
        for (Cell cell: filas) {                
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }       

}

}
```

Many simple questions can be answered by looking at the [quick guide](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) on the [poi](https://poi.apache.org/) website.

Comment: you just give me the perfect solution! thank you very much for your help, greetings

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the code, I think that `NullPointerException` will occur if the first row in the excel sheet is blank. So, I have created an Iterator on rows.

Try the below code:

```
package modleerjava;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class leerExcel {
public void readExcel(String rutaFile,String nombreFile, String sheetName ) 
 throws IOException {
    File file = new File ("C:/Users/Pablo/Desktop/prueba.xlsx"); 
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);  
    XSSFWorkbook excelWorkbook ; 
    excelWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    Sheet excelSheet = excelWorkbook.getSheet(sheetName); 
    //int filasCount = excelSheet.getLastRowNum()-excelSheet.getFirstRowNum(); 
    Iterator<Row> row = excelSheet.rowIterator();
    while(row.hasNext()) { 
        Row filas;
        filas = row.next();

        for (int j=0 ; j < filas.getLastCellNum(); j++) { 
            System.out.print(filas.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }       

}

 }
```

Comment: i have only one question about your fix , in "sheet.rowIterator()" it marks "sheet" and the suggestion says that i need to make a class named "sheet".

Comment: typo mistake, my bad. Check now

Comment: IT WORKED ! Thanks you so much for your help !